# OnKeyUp event in Access 2007

Tags: vba

I have a textbox and a label in an Access form. Whatever is typed in the textbox needs to be reflected/mirrored in the label and I must use the OnKeyUp event for the textbox. How can I do this?  This is a homework assignment.  I have no programming experience and this is my first programming class.  So far I have this:

```
Private Sub Text0_KeyUp(keycode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Label2 = Text0.Text.KeyUp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the change event of the textbox & set Label2.Caption = Text0.Text in that event.
The change event occurs when the contents of the textbox changes.

Answer (score 0):

inline with your KeyUp function.

```
Private Sub tbTextBox(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
   Dim textBoxtext As String 

   textBoxtext = Me.tbTextBox.text 'put the textbox text in the string
   lbLabel = textBoxText 'put the text in the string to the label
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I tested for you on Microsoft Access 2007:

```
Private Sub Text0_KeyUp(keycode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
  Me.Label2.Caption = Me.Text0.Text
End Sub
```

Where Me represents the current Form object.